# Web script groovy - Alfresco

Tags: java, maven, groovy, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to make a web script in groovy and run that web script on Alfresco. But, i don't know how to. I read tutorials but I haven't come to any conclusion...
Anyone knows all steps to run a web script in groovy ? Which files I need? 
My idea is to make a integration of one application groovy on Alfresco.

For example, i'm trying to test one of this web scripts: https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-groovy-webscripts

But i got the error :

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/alfresco/extension/alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent/1.3/alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent-1.3.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent:pom:1.3' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent for project: null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null for project null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException: Cannot find parent: org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent for project: null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null for project null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent for project: null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null for project null:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-webscripts:amp:null
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:508)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: POM 'org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent:pom:1.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent:pom:1.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    ... 21 more
```

I try too the web scripts already in Alfresco examples, but i got error, for example:

```
The Web Script /alfresco/s/default/surfbug has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like strictly a maven problem to me. The exception states that `Unable to download the artifact from any repository`. This means that you've got a dependency on something that can't be found in either your local repository or any of the default or configured remote repository.

The missing dependency is stated as `org.alfresco.extension:alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent:pom:1.3`. To get this to work, this artifact needs to be in your local repository. I couldn't find any reference to this in the common remote repositories, so it might be something you need to build from source.

The link you provided in your question is for a github project with the following code in its pom.xml file:

```
  <groupId>org.alfresco.extension</groupId>
  <artifactId>alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Notice that the groupId and artifactId match your missing dependency, but the version is different. If you've installed this sample, using `mvn install`, then version 1.4-SNAPSHOT of this dependency should already be in your local repository. You could search your pom files for the dependency on alfresco-groovy-webscripts-parent v1.3, and change it to 1.4-SNAPSHOT and try again.